# Pgfplot and sampling at specific points

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to understand how to use the `samples at` option with `...` from pgfplots. Consider the MWE

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line/.style={black, thick},
  declare function={foo(\x) =
    max(0, 4 + min(0, (\x-4)^3));
  },]
  \begin{axis}[xmin=-1, xmax=6, axis on top]
    \addplot[line, color=black, domain=-1:6]{foo(x)};
    \addplot[line, color=blue, samples at={-1, 2.4125, 4, 6}]{foo(x)};
    \addplot[line, color=red, samples at={-1, 2.4125,...,4, 6}]{foo(x)};
    \addplot[line, color=green, samples at={-1, ...,2.4125,...,4, ...,6}]{foo(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Drawing the lint without `samples at` produces artefacts due to the under sampling of the points in the mid region. The second `addplot`

```latex
\addplot[line, color=blue, samples at={-1, 2.4125, 4, 6}]{foo(x)};
```

Works as expected by adding the specific sampling points at the provided locations.

However, the third `addplot`

```latex
\addplot[line, color=red, samples at={-1, 2.4125,...,4, 6}]{foo(x)};
```

does not work. I expected it to add more samples in the range [2.4125,4], instead it does something weird. Finally, the last `addplot`

```latex
\addplot[line, color=green, samples at={-1, ...,2.4125,...,4, ...,6}]{foo(x)};
```

I expected to produce something similar to the plot without `samples at` except for additional points at 2.4125, 4 and 6. Instead the line seems to loop around!

I suspect I am misusing `samples at`, but I am not sure how to correct my usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify the step to fill the list. Otherwise it is set to 1. This is from pgfmanual.

> Normally, when a list item ... is encountered, there should already have been two list items before it, which where numbers. Examples of numbers are 1, -10, or -0.24. Let us call these numbers x and y and let d := y − x be their difference. Next, there should also be one number following the three dots, let us call this number z.
>
> In this situation, the part of the list reading “x,y,...,z” is replaced by “x, x + d, x + 2d, x + 3d, ..., x + md”, where the last dots are semantic dots, not syntactic dots. The value m is the largest number such that x + md ≤ z if d is positive or such that x + md ≥ z if d is negative.
>
> Perhaps it is best to explain this by some examples: The following  have the same effects:
>
> \foreach \x in {1,2,...,6} {\x, } yields 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
>
> \foreach \x in {1,2,3,...,6} {\x, } yields 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
>
> \foreach \x in {1,3,...,11} {\x, } yields 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11,
>
> \foreach \x in {1,3,...,10} {\x, } yields 1, 3, 5, 7, 9,
>
> \foreach \x in {0,0.1,...,0.5} {\x, } yields 0, 0.1, 0.20001, 0.30002, 0.40002,
>
> \foreach \x in {a,b,9,8,...,1,2,2.125,...,2.5} {\x, } yields a, b, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2.125, 2.25, 2.375, 2.5
>
> As can be seen, for fractional steps that are not multiples of 2−n for some small n, rounding errors can occur pretty easily. Thus, in the second last case, 0.5 should probably be replaced by 0.501 for robustness.
>
> There is another special case for the ... statement: If the ... is used right after the first item in the list, that is, if there is an x, but no y, the difference d obviously cannot be computed and is set to 1 if the number z following the dots is larger than x and is set to −1 if z is smaller.

So if you want samples from -1 to 2.4125 to 4 to 6, you can code

```
\addplot[line, color=cyan, samples at={-1,-.5,...,2.4125, 2.5,2.8,...,4, 4,4.6,...,6}]{foo(x)};
```

we start at -1 to 2.4125 by 0.5, then from 2.5 to 4 by 0.3 and from 4 to 6 by 0.6.

You can compare with

```
\addplot[line, color=black, domain=-1:6, samples=100]{foo(x)};
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Is there no way to change the default step size?

Comment: I don't think we can change the default step…